# Expiring key/value repository. Java

Tags: java, repository

The following code is in-memory repository that stores key/value pairs. It will be used on our server to keep information about active clients. Clients send keepalive messages to indicate that them are active. Important point: the information of inactive (expired) clients should be removed from repository ASAP. A client sends keepalive message every 30 seconds and I expect 1000 clients connected.

The methods usage:

- put -  adds new client (registration)
- touch - updates client "last seen time"  (keepalive)
- remove - removes client (client leaves)
- get - looks for client with given client's ID

I would like to get feedback on:

- Coding style
- Possible performance problem
- Suggestions for improvement.

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;


public class ExpiringKeyValueRepository<K, V> {

    final public static long MAX_LIVE_TIME = Long.MAX_VALUE;

    private Node<K, V> first = null;
    private Node<K, V> last = null;

    private long timeToLive;

    private ReentrantReadWriteLock rwLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    private Lock writeLock = rwLock.writeLock();
    private Lock readLock = rwLock.readLock();

    private Condition checkCondition =  writeLock.newCondition();

    private HashMap<K, Node<K, V>> map = new HashMap<>();
    private Cleaner<K, V> cleaner = new Cleaner<>(this);
    private Thread cleanerThread = null;

    /**
     * Constructs an empty repository with the given live time period of stored elements
     * 
     * @param timeToLive the live time in milliseconds
     * 
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if given live time is zero or negative
     */
    public ExpiringKeyValueRepository(long timeToLive) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException {

        if (timeToLive <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        this.timeToLive = timeToLive;
    }

    /**
     * Starts the repository.
     * Call of this method on already running 
     * repository has no effect
     */
    synchronized public void start() {

        if (cleaner.isRunning())
            return;

        cleanerThread = new Thread(cleaner);
        cleaner.stopped = false;
        cleanerThread.start();  
    }

    /**
     * Stops the repository. The method also removes
     * all stored entries. Call of this method on already 
     * stopped repository has no effect
     */
    synchronized public void stop() {

        if (!cleaner.isRunning())
            return;

        try {
            cleaner.stop(); 
            cleanerThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e){};

        reset ();
    }

    /**
     * Adds the given key/value mapping to this repository 
     * if the repository doesn't contain mapping for the given key
     *  
     * @param key the key
     * @param value the value
     * 
     * @return true if this repository did not already 
     *              contain mapping for the specified key
     * 
     * @throws NullPointerException if either key or value is null
     * @throws IllegalStateException if repository is not running
     */
    public boolean put(K key, V value) 
    throws NullPointerException, IllegalStateException {
        
        if (!cleaner.isRunning())
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        
        Objects.requireNonNull(key);
        Objects.requireNonNull(value);

        writeLock.lock();

        try {

            Node<K, V> node = map.get(key);

            if (node == null) {
                linkLast(key, value);
                map.put(key, last);
                return true;
            } 
            
            return false;
            
        } finally {
            rwLock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    
    /**
     * Updates expiration time of entry mapped to the given key
     * 
     * @param key the key
     * 
     * @return true if mapping for given key found
     * 
     * @throws IllegalStateException if repository is not running
     */
    public boolean touch(K key)  throws IllegalStateException {
        
        if (!cleaner.isRunning())
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        
        Objects.requireNonNull(key);
        
        writeLock.lock();
        try {
            Node<K, V> node = map.get(key);
            
            if (node == null) 
                return false;
                
            node.updateExpirationTime(timeToLive);
            moveToEnd(node);
            checkCondition.notify();
            
            return true;
            
        } finally {
            rwLock.writeLock().unlock();
        }   
    }

    /**
     * Returns the value with which the given key is associated.
     * If this repository contains no mapping for the key or entry 
     * is expired then the method returns null. 
     * 
     * @param key the key
     * 
     * @return the value with which the given key is associated, returns null 
     *         if no mapping for the key or entry is expired
     *         
     * @throws IllegalStateException if repository is not running
     */ 
    public V get(K key) throws IllegalStateException {
        
        if (!cleaner.isRunning())
            throw new IllegalStateException();

        readLock.lock();

        try {

            Node<K, V> node = map.get(key);
            return node == null || node.isExpired() ? null : node.getValue();

        } finally {
            readLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes the association for the given key
     * 
     * @param key the key whose mapping is to be removed
     * 
     * @return the previous value associated with key, 
     *         or null if there was no mapping for key
     *         
     * @throws IllegalStateException if repository is not running
     */
    public V remove(K key) throws IllegalStateException {

        if (!cleaner.isRunning())
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        
        rwLock.writeLock().lock();

        try {

            V value = removeNoLock(key);
            checkCondition.notify();
            return value;

        } finally {
            rwLock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    private void reset () {
        first = last = null;
        map.clear();
    }

    private V removeNoLock(K key) {

        if (!cleaner.isRunning())
            throw new IllegalStateException();

        final Node<K, V> node = map.remove(key);

        if (node == null)
            return null;

        unlink(node);
        return node.getValue();
    }

    private void linkLast(K key, V value) {

        final Node<K, V> node = new Node<K, V>(key, value, timeToLive);
        linkLast(node);
    }

    private void linkLast(Node<K, V> node) {

        if (!cleaner.isRunning())
            throw new IllegalStateException();

        node.setLinks(last, null);
        last = node;

        if (last.prev == null)
            first = node;
        else
            last.prev.next = node;
    }

    private Node<K, V> unlink(Node<K, V> node) {

        if (!cleaner.isRunning())
            throw new IllegalStateException();

        if (first == null)
            return null;

        final Node<K, V> prev = node.prev;
        final Node<K, V> next = node.next;

        if (prev == null) {
            first = next;
        } else {
            prev.next = next;
            node.prev = null; // Help GC
        }

        if (next == null) {
            last = prev;
        } else {
            next.prev = prev;
            node.next = null; // Help GC
        }

        return node;
    }

    private void moveToEnd(Node<K, V> node) {

        if (first == null)
            return; // should not be here

        if (first == last)
            return;

        unlink(node);
        linkLast(node);
    }

    private static class Node<K, V> extends SimpleEntry<K, V> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private Node<K, V> prev = null;
        private Node<K, V> next = null;

        private long expirationTime;

        private Node(K key, V value, long liveTime) {
            super(key, value);
            updateExpirationTime(liveTime);
        }

        private Node(Node<K, V> prev, Node<K, V> next, K key, V value, long liveTime) {
            this(key, value, liveTime);
            setLinks(prev, next);
        }

        private void setLinks(Node<K, V> prev, Node<K, V> next) {
            this.prev = prev;
            this.next = next;
        }

        private long timeTillExpiraton() {
            return expirationTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        private boolean isExpired() {
            return expirationTime - System.currentTimeMillis() <= 0;
        }

        public void updateExpirationTime(long liveTime) {
            expirationTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + liveTime;
        }
    }


    private static class Cleaner<K, V> implements Runnable {

        private ExpiringKeyValueRepository<K, V> rep;
        private boolean stopped = true;

        private Lock writeLock;
        private Condition checkCondition;

        private Cleaner(ExpiringKeyValueRepository<K, V> repository) {
            this.rep = repository;
            this.writeLock = repository.writeLock;
            this.checkCondition = repository.checkCondition;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            writeLock.lock();
            
            try {

                while (!stopped) {

                    while (rep.first != null && rep.first.isExpired()) {
                        rep.removeNoLock(rep.first.getKey());
                    };

                    long timeToWait = rep.first == null ? MAX_LIVE_TIME : rep.first.timeTillExpiraton();
                    try {
                        checkCondition.await(timeToWait, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {} ;
                }


            } finally {
                writeLock.unlock();
            }
        }

        private void stop() {

            writeLock.lock();
            try {

                if (!stopped) 
                    stopped = true;

            } finally {
                writeLock.unlock();
            }
        }

        private boolean isRunning () {
            return !stopped;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice implementation, the code is well commented and easy to understand. My suggestions:

### Design

`Node` keeps two pointers for the previous and the next. The repository also keeps two pointers for the first and last node. I think that is because `HashMap` is not ordered. Have you considered using `LinkedHashMap`? It keeps the insertion order so the oldest nodes are always on top and you don't need to do all the linking/unlinking.

To update the keepalive of one node in a `LinkedHashMap` you can remove, update and re-add the node.

### Exception handling

- Exception messages are missing in all exceptions. The JavaDoc helps but it's important to provide a message in the exception. It's odd that invoking `.get(key)` throws and `IllegalStateException` without a message.
- Each method checks if the repository is started, otherwise throws an exception. To simplify that consider to start the repository directly in the constructor.

### Stopping the repository issue

```
public class ExpiringKeyValueRepository<K, V> {
    //...
    synchronized public void stop() {
        //...
        try {
            cleaner.stop(); 
            cleanerThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e){};
        //...
    }
    private static class Cleaner<K, V> implements Runnable {
        //...
        @Override
        public void run() {
                //...
                while (!stopped) {
                    //...
                    long timeToWait = rep.first == null ? MAX_LIVE_TIME : rep.first.timeTillExpiraton();
                    try {
                        checkCondition.await(timeToWait, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {} ;
                }
                //...
        }
        private void stop() {
            writeLock.lock();
            try {
                if (!stopped) 
                    stopped = true;
            } finally {
                writeLock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Consider this scenario:

1. Start the repository: the thread `cleaner` is launched.
2. Add and remove all keys.
3. There are no keys left so the `cleaner` decides to go to sleep forever.
4. Stop the repository: the main thread sets `stopped=true` and waits  for cleaner to stop (`.join`) but it will never happen because it's sleeping.

Also the method `Cleaner#stop` is a little bit overkill. It is a private method that is invoked only by the parent class within an already synchronized method. I think it can be safely changed to:

```
private void stop(){
    stopped=true;
}
```

### Alternative

The Google library [Guava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava) provides [Cache](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html) that should fit your use case. See a simple usage:

```
Cache<Integer, String> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                    .expireAfterAccess(1000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .build();
// Add entry
cache.put(1, "user1");
// Get the value
assertEquals("user1",cache.getIfPresent(1));
// Refresh the entry (update keep alive)
cache.getIfPresent(1);
// Remove a key
cache.invalidate(1);
assertNull(cache.getIfPresent(1));
// Clear all keys
cache.cleanUp();
```

It is also thread-safe and can be used by multiple concurrent threads.

Comment: @Markc Thanks for so deep and detailed review.
1. About usage of LinkedHashMap.  I checked this option. The reason to not use it is that remove/add on timestamp update may cause map rehashing which is time consumed operation with map locking.
2. Cleaner stopping issue. You are right, this is a bug.  I will fix it by insertion of checkCondition.notify() in Cleaner#stop, so cleaner will wakeup, check flag and exit.
3. As for other things you mentioned  - you are right, I will fix it. Guava usage looks reasanable and I will check it too.

Comment: @bw_dev I am glad I could help ;) If you are satisfied with this answer consider to accept it.